# Saddle keep tilting. Which spare to use to replace it?

Tags: saddle

The saddle of this bike keep tilting, no matter how strong I tighten the bolts.

[image]
Therefore I am thinking of replacing it.

Can I replace only the fixture, or do I need to replace the entire pipe? Also, is it a specific type that I need to ask for when buying the spare?

Comment: Replace the seatpost with one that has a built-in clamp. The combination of post and clamp on your bike is heavy, prone to that kind of failure and normally a feature of cheap bikes. Try to find an aluminium post of the correct diameter. You'll keep the saddle that you are used to.  Note that you may also find a similar replacement clamp at your LBS. But still you'll get an Al post for the same price I'd guess.

Comment: Could be your saddle is too far forward or backward on the rails, and you're sitting in such a way to exert leverage on the clamp.  Is the bike frame too small for you?   I have this problem with my folding bike, and have to reset the saddle and seat post every couple weeks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First thing to do is double check the other side is put together right, namely that the toothy bits are engaging.

If so, probably what's happening is the teeth that are supposed to hold the angle adjustment in place got rounded off from prior incidents of slipping.

These kinds of clamps come in one very commonly seen size, 22.2mm aka 7/8", and a couple weird ones that are mostly the domain of antique bikes. You might as well bring in the old one to match, or put a ruler across it to confirm it wants a 22.2mm post end (different from the seatpost size proper because usually pipe style ones taper at the clamp end). The rail mount part is universal among normal single rail saddles.

Most bike shops with any kind of family/casual customer base accumulate a big heavy box of new replacement clamps because they come with certain brands of  saddle, but most bikes don't actually need them because they have posts with integrated clamps. So from a shop like that they're pretty ubiquitous and cheap.

Comment: I think we once recycled a box of just seatpost clamps.  Got pizza that day for the shop.

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is that the other side is not sufficiently tightened. To me it looks like there is too much of the bolt showing on this side, which implies that it may not be able to be tightened completely on the other side. This may lead to slipping.

The amount of protruding bolt on each side of the seat should be roughly the same. If you are uncertain take a picture of the other side as well.

You may also want to check that the threads on the bolt are not damaged. If it was overtightened the threads may have been stripped, making it impossible to tighten.

Otherwise, it could be wear to the clamp front surface as others have suggested.

Comment: If it's overtightened on one end it can become tight without being properly tightened since the bolt gets pulled too far to one side. I've seen people tighten only one side and then try to tighten the other side and have difficulties since they couldn't tighten the opposing side enough. I don't recall exactly what was happening, but it wasn't working until they loosened the overtightened side.

Comment: You reminded me that it may be stripped threads preventing sufficient tightening.

Comment: Excellent point - I never thought of that but thinking back its certainly possible.